# Mobile Application as Two Versions based on the same app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im currently developing an application for mobile phones (smart phones). My mind have picked up the path of distrubuting the app in two different versions. One that are free but do have adds and banners in it, and one that you have to pay for that doesn't have the adds or the banners.

So basically, both of the versions are based on the same program but the main difference is that they either are bound of ads or not. This is clear to me and I have no questions acording this idea. But..

I found it pretty tricky to organize my projects for my application, to be clear, Im developing the application for Android, Windows Phone 7 and also iOS. For the moment Im trying to organize my Android project/projects in Eclipse, but Im quite confused in which way I should have the projects saved.

I mean, if I for example have two different projects in Eclipse, one that have ads and one that don't. If i need to fix something in the application I need to make the changes in both of the projects, and Im sure that this isn't the right way to handle these things. So if someone have any experience in having your application in two different version but with the same functionality (except of the ads) feel free to explain to me how you usually handle these kind of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For previous projects I've worked on, I've used a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects).

Basically, you put all of your code, UI, resources etc inside of the library project.

Then create two android projects with the classpaths similar to this:
com.yourapp.example
com.yourapp.example.free

In each of the two android projects, include your library project as a library and create two manifests for each version of your app. This is a very simple overview but using this approach you can easily create two versions of your app using the same codebase.

Comment: Thank you Laurence Dawson, I think I catched the idea on how the project structure should be built now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, might be worth mentioning that if you have say layout.xml in your library project and layout.xml in com.yourapp.example, the latter will be used. This can be useful for creating layouts with ads etc.

Answer (score 0):

Usually most of my apps are showing ads. So I implement a free-version of an app and another version (without any function), which works like an unlocker.
But you can also implement an in-app store where users can buy features like "ads-free".

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sence at all to me.